# App crashes on iPad simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am building a universal app. App is working fine for iPhone 5 and iPhone 4(different storyboard) but it crashes when trying to run it for iPad 6.1

This is the error:

```
-[AccountTableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab52620
 2013-08-19 21:13:35.527 [6871:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught        exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AccountTableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab52620'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x2131012 0x1c26e7e 0x21bc4bd 0x2120bbc 0x212094e 0x2c1a 0xb68157 0xb68747 0xb6994b 0xb7acb5 0xb7bbeb 0xb6d698 0x2b10df9 0x2b10ad0 0x20a6bf5 0x20a6962 0x20d7bb6 0x20d6f44 0x20d6e1b 0xb6917a 0xb6affc 0x252d 0x2455)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a `UINavigationController` method `topViewController` on a `UITableView` instance `AccountTableViewController`.

Without code, it's a little difficult to be more specific, but maybe you want to be calling this method on the `UITableView`'s navigation controller?